# JS class child returns undefined while accessing parent constructor

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

I am getting undefined value while calling `rnd.winner()` in child class. This should return the name of player from parent like JOHN. Calling test function from child returns correct value of `win()` from parent. Calling `super.constructor.name` as return status in child returns parents class name -> `player` Now why is that?

```js
class player {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.win = 0;
    this.loss = 0;
  };
  win() {
    return this.win;
  };
  loss() {
    return this.loss;
  };
};

class scoreBoard extends player {
  constructor(round) {
    super();
    this.round = round;
    this.emblem = 0;
  };
  add() {
    return this.round.push([...this.round].pop() + 1);
  }
  winner() {
    return super.name;
  };
  loser() {
    return super.constructor.name;
  };
  emblem() {
    return this.emblem;
  };
  test() {
    return super.win();
  };
};
let plr = new player("JOHN"),
  rnd = new scoreBoard([0]);
console.log(plr.name, rnd.winner(), rnd.test());
```

Comment: Don't use `super` with plain data properties. They always exist on your current instance. Use `this.name` instead.

Comment: Why do you feel that a `scoreBoard` is an extension of a `player`? I don't really get the logic. For a scoreboard (with winner and loser methods) you need at least two players, so I don't rally get what you had hoped for in the inheritance relationship. And why is `round` an array? `constructor.name` has *nothing* to do with your `name` property. It is a predefined property of functions (as `constructor` is a function).

Answer (score 0):

> Calling `super.constructor.name` as return status in child returns parents class name (`player`). Now why is that?

Because that's what `super` does. It does not take the own `constructor` property, but the `constructor` property on the object that you inherit from. For `scoreBoard.prototype` methods, that's the `player.prototype` object, and its `.constructor.name` is `"player"`.

There is no reason to use `super` at all, unless you are overwriting an inherited method (or the constructor). This means not to use `super` with plain data properties ever. They always exist on your current instance. Use `this.…` instead.

> I am getting `undefined` value while calling `rnd.winner()` in child class. This should return the name of player from parent like JOHN.

That's because `.name` was not initialised, as your child class did not pass an argument through to the parent constructor in `super()`. In fact, your `rnd` doesn't know about the `plr` instance at all.

In any case, inheritance seems to be the wrong tool to describe the relation between a player and a scoreboard. [Use composition instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) - e.g. the scoreboard holding an array of player objects to display.

Comment: Well actually if I do something like `super(plr.name);` (what looks totally incorrect to me) and `return this.name` it finally returns the correct name. Now it is clear to me, I will work and find a good way to deal with `this`!

Comment: Yes, that's a way to make it work, and yes it's totally incorrect since a scoreboard is not a player.